# Laptop keyboard typing foreign language characters on " (like äïöü)?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard, language

I have a DELL XPS laptop bought last year, and I hadn't been using it for quite some time, just got it back into my possession in March/April...

I use it mostly at home, so don't carry it elsewhere. It's working great apart from the keyboard.

The " key on my laptop is kind of messy. I press it and it doesn't appear on the screen. I have to press space bar or any other button that's not foreign to make it appear on the screen.

Here's the keyboard buttons pressed after the " button in the alphabets...:

```
ä"bë"f"g"hï"j"k"l"m"nö"p"q'r"tü"v"w"xÿ"z... ??
```

I don't know what's wrong, maybe some regional/language setting I'm missing to check on my system.

OS: Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current keyboard layout is US-International; this activates various [**dead keys**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) for composing accented letters. Switch the layout to US if you don't want this.

Comment: Thanks! I removed US International layout by mistake... would that affect anything? (instead of changing to US, I "removed" US-International from the layout list)

Comment: It will make it unavailable for switching to using the assigned key sequence.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You're on a roll with these Dead-key-layout questions today.